# Difference between website and web service

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, web

What is the difference between normal website and a web service? could you please explane with in an example

Answer (score 0):

A website is a place for people to go to receive information, like pictures, and information on a certain subject.
A web service is a place where you can receive a service, paid or unpaid, an example would be www.xe.com, there you can recieve a service for free to find out what a US$ is against a NZ$ for example.

Cheers